# Excel VBA - Do While Loop - Move to next row

Tags: loops, do-while

I am attempting to add comments to a report output based on different cell values.

I have chosen the Do While...Loop as the condition needs to cease once the Unq identifier in column B stops being present in consecutive rows rather than continuing through the entire sheet. The Unq identifier could be found in 1 - 50 rows. Col K value is tested and if found col N value and the original cell (LastCell) are compared.
This seems to be working, however, I can not get the Loop to move to the next row.
I am using rng = rng + 1, but instead of moving down a row, it adds 1 to the Unq identifier, ie: 123 becomes 124.

How do I move down a row? Alternatively, is there a better way of addressing this?

FYI, I am amending someone else's code, not starting from scratch.

```
Sub play()
 
Dim Unq As Long
Dim Cell As Range
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim rng As Range
 
For Each Cell In Range("U2:U" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
        If Int(Range("B" & Cell.Row).Value) <> Unq And Len(Range("A" & Cell.Row).Value) > 0 Then
            Unq = Int(Range("B" & Cell.Row).Value)
            Cell.Value = Cell.Offset(0, -6).Value - Cell.Offset(0, -5).Value
        If Cell.Offset(0, -15) = "REG" Then
            GoTo Skip1
       
Skip1:
  
    'Bonus identified - No requirement to investigate
        If Cell.Offset(0, -2).Value <> 0 Or Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> 0 Then
       
        Set LastCell = Cell
        Set rng = Cell.Offset(0, -19)
                        
        Do While rng.Value = Unq
           
            If rng.Offset(0, 9).Value = "BONUS" And rng.Offset(0, 12).Value = LastCell.Value Then
            LastCell.Activate
            Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Bonus Paid"
            ElseIf rng.Offset(0, 9).Value = "BONUS" And rng.Offset(0, 12).Value <> LastCell.Value Then
            LastCell.Activate
            Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Retention Bonus Paid"
            Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Variation managed by macro"
            Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Variation managed by macro"
            Cell.Offset(0, 4).Value = Date
            Cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = "Yes"
        Else:
         rng = rng + 1
        
       
    End If
                  
    Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously not one of my brightest days yesterday!

Amended code to `Do Until rng.value <> Unq Or Cell.Offset(0,1 <> ""`

Changed

```
Else:
rng = rng + 1
```

to

```
Else:
Set rng = rng.offset(1, 0)
```

Works a treat.